# SQL sometimes need "`". Why?

Tags: sql

If I do this:

```
SELECT range_name, club_id FROM range WHERE range_id=1
```

I get a syntax error. But if I do this:

```
SELECT range_id, local_id FROM range_relation WHERE id=1
```

It works just fine. To fix my syntax error in case one, I need to add "`" like this:

```
SELECT range_name, club_id FROM `range` WHERE range_id=1
```

Then it works fine. Why is "`" not always required around the table, only sometimes?

Comment: Maybe range is a reserved word?

Comment: `range` is a reserved word that represents a SQL function/routine. It appears you've also named a table `range`. The backticks differentiate the function from the table in this case.

Comment: Thank you, of course but I would never had guessed myself